# Quick way to connect to a remote MySql Database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

I wanted to connect to a database from within a Java-based framework. This essentially involves writing code to connect to a database. However, I cannot modify any build.xml file or so such as in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html or download packages such as mysql-connector-java. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: You are writing a framework and you want to develop some connect to the database functionality for it?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I need to have java code to connect to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connect = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?"
          + "user=myusername&password=mypassword");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect
      .prepareStatement("select * from employees");
 ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next()) {
  //display text
}
preparedStatement.close();
connect.close();
```

- As you can see, I have assumed that you have a mysql database called `dbname` running on localhost and the credentials are `myusername` and `mypassword`. Also, the above code assumes that you have a `employees` table in the database
- I have used `PreparedStatement` so that it precompiles. It is more useful when you have params for the query. You could use Callable statement as well.

Comment: Will I need to download any library or so for this purpose? Thanks a lot btw...

Comment: add the jar at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j to your classpath

Comment: Do I need to include anything for this?